# Why doesn't SourceSafe respect the "Open this database next time..." option?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Using Visual SourceSafe's "Open SourceSafe Database..." command, there is an option at the bottom of the dialog to "Open this database next time I run Visual SourceSafe."

Typically, when checking this box the most recent opened VSS DB is opened immediately upon launching VSS (even if it's a second instance of VSS running).

I'm seeing this option not respected. All launches of VSS result in the same DB being opened at launch.

Removing all the registry entries under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SourceSafe\Databases` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SourceSafe\Databases` doesn't help.

Additionally, the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Sourcesafe\Current Database` value was accurately pointing to the DB I wanted to be opened, but not the DB that was VSS was actually opening. Same with the similar value under `HKLM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An environment variable had been set to force that particular database.

When SSDIR is set, the VSS dialog option is ignored.

Clearing the SSDIR variable fixed the issue.